# Are bathtub sizes the rough in size or the tub interior size?

Tags: bathtub

I am looking at installing a tub and the sizes are not clear what they are.

For example, [the "Amiga" bath](http://72.0%E2%80%B3%20L%20x%2036.0%E2%80%B3%20W%20x%2021.0%E2%80%B3%20H) gives dimensions 72.0″ L x 36.0″ W x 21.0″ H. Is the 6 feet the size of the rough in, or is it somthing else?

In other words if the studs of the wall are 6 feet apart will the bath fit in there?

Answer (score 1):

All tubs come with "rough in" size specifications which indicate necessary framing/opening dimensions for your unit specs. They can often be found online.

Interestingly, yours says:

> Dimensions provided on rough-in diagrams are nominal. Measure your actual unit upon receipt and build according to the actual dimensions.

"[image]

Comment: This is correct. The answer is "it depends". I'd consider building to 72-1/2" and fur down later (on the short wall) for a perfect fit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In the US bathtubs generally come in 5 foot and 6 foot lengths.  This is the actual length of the unit, and hence the rough in stud to stud distance should be the same.

Comment: In my experience, fitting a thing in a roughed-in opening of exactly the same dimensions is a recipe for frustration. You always want some space for play.

Comment: I agree with @isherwoods comment, some tubs and or surrounds are slightly longer and some slightly shorter. A measurement of the tub + at least 1/4 to 1/2" is what I use you don't want the fit two tight as that can void the warranty on the molded tubs I have installed.